# How to draw line after every group in SQL Server Reporting Services based on a date?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I would like to draw a line after every group as depicted with red line in the image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your report appears to have a dark line under each `TOTAL` cell in the `Effective Date` column?  In your report designer, just select the long table cell to the right of that one and add in a border on the bottom of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the total row, expand BorderColor in the Properties window and select the color Red for the bottom border.